# Xdebug 3 is installed and showing on CLI but not showing in browser using phpinfo

Tags: macos, magento, php-7.4, php, xdebug-3

I have installed xdebug 3 on Mac M1 and when I run php -v it shows me that the xdebug is installed. I am sharing some valuable information for you below.

```
php -v
PHP 7.4.22 (cli) (built: Jul 29 2021 09:14:29) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

```
locate php.ini
/Library/WebServer/Documents/CP/php.ini.sample
/Library/WebServer/Documents/leohamel/php.ini.sample
/Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/php.ini.sample
/Library/WebServer/Documents/magento2/php.ini.sample
/Library/WebServer/Documents/magento2/vendor/magento/magento2-base/php.ini.sample
/Library/WebServer/Documents/magento_old/php.ini.sample
/System/Library/Templates/Data/private/etc/php.ini.default
/System/Volumes/Update/mnt1/System/Library/Templates/Data/private/etc/php.ini.default
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.9/.bottle/etc/php/8.0/php.ini
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.22/.bottle/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
/opt/homebrew/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
/opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/php.ini
/private/etc/#php.ini#
/private/etc/php.ini-5.2-previous
/private/etc/php.ini-previous
/private/etc/php.ini.default
/private/etc/php.ini.default-5.2-previous
/private/etc/php.ini.default-previous
/private/etc/php.ini.default-previous~orig
/private/etc/php.ini~
/usr/local/Cellar/valet-php@7.1/7.1.25/.bottle/etc/valet-php/7.1/php.ini
/usr/local/Cellar/valet-php@7.2/7.2.13/.bottle/etc/valet-php/7.2/php.ini
```

I am using this php.ini /opt/homebrew/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
and it is also showing in

```
php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/homebrew/etc/php/7.4
Loaded Configuration File:         /opt/homebrew/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /opt/homebrew/etc/php/7.4/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /opt/homebrew/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
```

```
which php
/opt/homebrew/opt/php@7.4/bin/php
```

Here is what the xdebug wizard is showing me when I paste the phpinfo output there

```
Installation Wizard
Summary
Xdebug installed: no
Server API: FPM/FastCGI
Windows: no
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 7.4.22
Zend API nr: 320190902
PHP API nr: 20190902
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: no
OPcache Loaded: yes
Configuration File Path: /opt/homebrew/etc/php/7.4
Configuration File: /opt/homebrew/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
Extra Configuration Files Path: /opt/homebrew/etc/php/7.4/conf.d
Extra Configuration Files:
/opt/homebrew/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
Extensions directory: /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902
```

Can you tell me please what am I doing wrong? or how can I see the xdebug in the browser output?

Answer (score 0):

Some builds of php has splitting configurations to areas: cli, fpm, etc.
In such cases, if you want to enable xdebug for fpm, you need add xdebug configuration to fpm area.
To find config files location for fpm type next:

```
php-fpm -i | grep ini
```

To check:

```
php-fpm -v
```

Comment: It turns out that I had to restart the php-fpm to fix this issue.